# Need to know who is hogging my bandwidth?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, wireshark, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Mac OS X how can I monitor what is using my internet connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/7184/on-mac-os-x-how-can-i-monitor-what-is-using-my-internet-connection)

I have an ethernet connection to my iMac and with Internet sharing I am broadcasting the wireless network from my mac rather than using a wireless router. I use it to connect other devices wirelessly to the internet. But this makes all the traffic flow through my iMac.

I wanted a way to analyze the traffic so that I know what connected devices are hogging the bandwidth at a given time and from which websites? I installed wireshark for mac and played around a little but it seems like an overkill when you first look at it.

Can someone please help with few instructions to get what I need or any other way other than using wireshark?

Thanks
Dev.

Comment: (As an aside: as far as I know, internet sharing only supports WEP, right? Just to be sure you know that is not very secure.)

Comment: @Arjan: Thats correct and thats why I wanna keep a tap to make sure no one is hogging my B/W ;)

Comment: @joe: yeah that post was helpful. But it was more about traffic from your own machine rather than any other machine on a WLAN and analyzing it with little-snitch rather than wireshark I think.