# Monitor network traffic on a per-app basis in OS X?

Tags: networking, macos, monitoring

Title says it all. I'm looking for an app for OS X that will tell me what applications are using the network and what their in/out is. I can get most of the way there with LittleSnitch but it's the bandwidth part that it fails at.

The only app I've come across that comes close is "Rubbernet" and while it does look like it would probably do what I want, it's very expensive (more than LittleSnitch) and doesn't look like it gets regular feature updates.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a free command line program called iftop that may be helpful. You can install it via Homebrew.

```
    brew install iftop
```

Once installed:

```
    sudo iftop -P -i en1
```

-i and the interface you wish to monitor.

Comment: Homebrew can be found and installed from http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/7184/on-mac-os-x-how-can-i-monitor-what-is-using-my-internet-connection). As explained in the comments below [@mikl's answer](https://superuser.com/a/7189/128794), Little Snitch provides a graphical interface showing per-app trafic. This functionality is available on the menu bar icon, "Show Network Monitor". It is still available when running in demo mode (free mode).

Also, a dmg is provided for the installation.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! If a question is a duplicate, you can Flag it for moderation, and provide a link in the Flag dialog box. It will also prevent an old 5 month old question from getting bumped up

Comment: Yeah I read this in the how-tos threads, but as a noob I couldn't flag. Now with the -1 I guess I am less likely to bother at all. Cheers.